# RegEx to normalize XML syntax

Tags: regex, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have an XML-code where some tags generate xml parse errors (Error #1090). The problem is in attributes that need to be quoted:

```
<div class=treeview>
```

Help me please to write a regular expression to make them as following:

```
<div class="treeview">
```

Comment: Try: `String.replace(/treeview/, "\"treeview\"")`

Comment: Thanks, but code may be like `<div anyattr=anyvalue>` and even `<div anyattr=anyvalue anotherattr=diffvalue>`. So that's why i'm asking on RegEx to cover any case. The only static things in it are: tag-name comes first right after "<", after space there comes a pair of attr=value without spaces between them.

Comment: Before even asking for help, try to do some effort, try something, write something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one will be correct:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /(\w+)(=)(\w+)/g;

trace('regexTest:', pString.replace(pattern, '$1$2"$3"'));
```

because, there must be 3 groups: attribute_name, = (equals), attribute_value

Comment: This one works fine. Just added space before first group

Answer (score 1):

Please, could you try the next code:

```
var regExp:RegExp = /(class\=)(\w+)/g;
var sourceText:String = "<div class=treeview>";
var replacedText:String = sourceText.replace(regExp, '$1"$2"');
trace(replacedText);
```

In a nutshell, this RegExp means:

1. Find 2 groups: (class=) and (any-word-after-it)
2. Add before and after the group 2 quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following regex>

```
regex = /(<div[^>]*class=)(\S+)([^>]*>)/g;
sourceString.replace(regex, '$1"$2"$3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a general purpose markup repair tool such as John Cowan's TagSoup. This is likely to be much more robust than anything you attempt yourself (for example, most of the suggested regular expressions don't even check that the keyword=value construct is within a start tag).

Comment: Thanks for advice. Yes, you are right, most of them are not intended to do other than replacing one keyword to another like it done by replace functions in other languages without regex. But for my small app with this little problem it's enough.